# Can a user mode fault cause a Blue Screen of Death?

Tags: windows, debugging, bsod

Can a user mode fault cause a [Blue Screen of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) (BSOD)? Is it possible that a memory access violation like double freeing memory can cause a blue screen or only a kernel mode exception (like a driver exception) cause Windows to crash?

Comment: "Note The names of the Notmyfault executable and driver highlight the fact that user mode cannot directly cause the system to crash. The Notmyfault executable can cause a crash only by loading a driver to perform an illegal operation for it in kernel mode." from **windows internal book six edition page**  564 notmyfaults is a test application that with inprper use of  Myfault.sys  cause to create blue screen  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly.

Direct fault will cause an exception and program crash. To cause a BSOD, the user mode application must communicate either directly or indirectly with a kernel mode driver that is possible not robust enough to protect itself from invalid user mode input.

Answer (score 0):

## Most of the time, no, but there is an exception.

A Blue Screen (known also as a *bug check*) only occurs when something goes wrong in kernel mode (for example, a [driver page faults at DISPATCH_LEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560244(v=vs.85).aspx)) or a hardware error.

User mode code usually cannot bring down the entire system (usually doing something that is not allowed will result in the program crashing or generating an error of some sort).

However, [bug check 0xED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560358(v=vs.85).aspx) can be caused directly by a user mode process. If the [`csrss.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client/Server_Runtime_Subsystem) process is killed (and also `wininit.exe` in Windows Vista and higher), it will blue screen the computer.

It is possible to kill [`winlogon.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winlogon) without causing [bug check 0xC000021A](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560177(v=vs.85).aspx) by first killing [`smss.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Manager_Subsystem) as Mark Russinovich explains in the 2005 article *[Running Windows with No Services](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2005/07/24/running-windows-with-no-services/)*:

> The reason we start [killing processes] with Smss.exe is that Smss.exe watches the back of Winlogon, the process it creates during the boot, so if you terminate Winlogon first Smss.exe gets upset and blue screens the machine with an error indicating that the Windows logon process terminated unexpectedly.

### This is the only case where a user mode application can *directly* cause a blue screen.