# C# Visual Studio 2015. Give application focus when starting from desktop

Tags: c#

When starting my application from the desktop icon the desktop still has focus. How do I give focus to the form that is showing instead of having to click on the form? I give focus to the Serial Number textbox but I still have to click the form to start typing in the textbox. I assume I will need to go to a location other than the Page Load.

```
 #region Page Load
    public void FBinterface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveControl = txtSerial;
        //CHECK FOR DB CONNECTION
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            lbl_connect.Text = "Database Connected";
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception expe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
        }
```

Comment: had you tried this.Focus()?

Comment: yep,  Still have to click on the form to gain focus away from the desktop.

Comment: then this.Activate should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bring my application window to the front?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282588/how-can-i-bring-my-application-window-to-the-front)

Comment: That seems to work. I knew it would be something of a "Duh" moment. Thank you.