# Display form on top in current software but not in other applications

Tags: c#, winforms

In my software, I am showing a form using `form.Show()`. This form should be on top, for that I am using -

```
form.TopMost = true;
```

When I open other applications while my software is still running, this inner form is shown on top of other applications too.

> I need to use `form.Show()` because I want other parts of master form
>   accessible while inner form is shown. So I can't use
>   `form.ShowDialog()`.
>   Not duplicate of [How can I bring my application window to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282588/how-can-i-bring-my-application-window-to-the-front/11941579#11941579)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bring my application window to the front?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282588/how-can-i-bring-my-application-window-to-the-front)

Comment: @ZoltánTamási The issue here is to show the form on top in current software but not in other applications.

Comment: My answer won't *force* the form on top of other applications, like `TopMost` does. Also, what is the sens in showing a form on top of your software when it's not active?

Comment: @ZoltánTamási I wished it works but its not working. There is some background activity on master form while the child form is active or inactive. So it needed to be shown.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Thanks, I achieved the behavior I wanted. I posted answer below.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question-
To achieve the above purpose, there is a need of creating an owned window by displaying it with the Show(owner) overload. Or by explicitly assigning its Owner property. No need to keep `form.TopMost = true`. Instead, It should be -

```
form.TopLevel = true; //Its true by default.
form.Show(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only really robust technique was suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11941579/1323504), as follows.

```
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
form.Show();
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```