# Any Possibilities for Simplfy my C# Code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I am developing winform application using C# and I need to simplfy. So please help me anyone how to Simplfy below my code . I have given below am using code.

```
try
        {
            object countnew = ((DataTable)grid_cheque.DataSource).Compute("Count(ChequeStatus)", "ChequeStatus = 'New'");
            object countIssued = ((DataTable)grid_cheque.DataSource).Compute("Count(ChequeStatus)", "ChequeStatus = 'Issued'");
            object countCancelled = ((DataTable)grid_cheque.DataSource).Compute("Count(ChequeStatus)", "ChequeStatus = 'Cancelled'");
            object countDishonour = ((DataTable)grid_cheque.DataSource).Compute("Count(ChequeStatus)", "ChequeStatus = 'DisHonour'");

            this.lblNew.Text = ERPModule.isnull(Convert.ToString(countnew), "0");
            this.lbl_Issued.Text = ERPModule.isnull(Convert.ToString(countIssued), "0");
            this.lblCancel.Text = ERPModule.isnull(Convert.ToString(countCancelled), "0");
            this.lbldishonour.Text = ERPModule.isnull(Convert.ToString(countDishonour), "0");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Crystal ball says that the Default property is the problem, this code won't work when it creates a new Form object every time you use it.  Workaround is auto frm = Accounts...Default; frm.Show(); frm.BringToFront();

Answer (score 0):

based on answer :

> [How can I bring my application window to the front?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282588/how-can-i-bring-my-application-window-to-the-front#comment54864241_5282613)

Control.BringToFront will bring a control to the front of the hosting control, for example you might bring a TextBox in front of a Label to make sure that the label's whitespace does not obscure part of the TextBox. Form has inherited this from Control, and it can be used to change the z-order of the Form when it is an MDI child - i.e. the Form is hosted in another Form. It will not bring a form in front of another application.